# Does any of the currently available editors support Ruby's hash colon?

Tags: ruby, syntax, editor, syntax-error, syntax-checking

In Ruby 1.9 `hash = {:one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3}` is now written as:

```
hash = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
}
```

However neither the current version of TextMate (1.5.10 (1623)) nor the current version of Redcar (0.10) recognize this as valid syntax, stumbling over the colon and hurting kitties in the process.

Are there any editors that recognize the new hash syntax?
(Feel free to praise Vim / Emacs, but please try to include some non-console editors.)

Comment: neither vim nor emacs are necessarily console-only editors anymore.

Comment: You could try to add your own extension to the TextMate grammar: http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#language%5Fgrammars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that your TextMate is pointing to Ruby 1.9.x rather than the default system Ruby install? I'm using TextMate with RVM, using 1.9.2 as the default Ruby. TextMate runs the above code just fine.

Comment: You're right. TextMate is still using the system Ruby. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Just to be friendly to googlers: add rvm-auto-ruby to the TM_RUBY in your TextMate Shell Variables like so http://cl.ly/23Yl

Comment: michaelmichael michaelmichael! Thankyouthankyou thankyouthankyou!